# get data with types from mongodb, nextjs

Tags: mongodb, next.js

I have nextjs project where I use MongoDB to get data, so when I fetch data I want to get types, I show you what result I want to get.

please consider that, I need such an array because I want to know what type of data is coming, when I get “_id”, “typeof” gives me “String” and I want to get that _id is a “type: ObjectId”, and so on

for example:

```
[
  {
    _id: "323030049934bwd",
    type: ObjectId,
  },
  {
    name: "David",
    type: String,
  },
  {
    active: false,
    type: boolean,
  },
];
```

// this is code where I get data from mongodb without types

```
import clientPromise from "../../../lib/mongo/mongo";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const client = await clientPromise;
  try {
    await client.connect();

    const allData = await client
      .db()
      .collection(req.query.collection[0])
      .find({})
      .toArray();

    return res.send(allData);
  } finally {
    await client.close();
  }
}
```

I hope I did to describe my situation